# Apache kafka frequently connect and close connection in nodejs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-node

In my node application I am using kafka with `kafka-node` npm package and I have custom connection check flow like below,

```
client.on("close", () => {
  console.log("kafka close");
});

client.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("kafka connect");
});

client.on("reconnect", () => {
  console.log("kafka re-connect"); 
});
```

while on real time that kafka logged like below,

```
kafka close
kafka close
kafka close
kafka close
kafka close
kafka close
kafka close
kafka close
kafka connect
kafka close
kafka connect
kafka close
kafka connect
```

I don't know why kafka react like this